# Save logo as a GEE image asset

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am simply trying to ingest a logo of my institution as an ee.Image asset in Google Earth Engine. The original file was a *.jpg. I loaded that into QGIS, and exported it as a *.tif file, applying a EPSG:4326 datum (no projection). In QGIS, I used QGIS > Raster > Translate (Convert Format) to convert the initial *.jpg into a *.tif. However, something must still be wrong as I am unable to ingest this image as a GEE asset. I have failed in multiple attempts to ingest this image, and have been getting the following error messages when the ingest Tasks fail in ~ 40 seconds.

Error messages:
Error: Image extends outside the [-90, 90] latitude range by more than one pixel. Found Bounding box (x=0..1390, y=0..862)

I attach the initial *.jpg for reference.

Initial *.jpg
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your Raster Image Asset must be a GeoTiff.  As the rasters in Earth Engine are used for geographic image processing, it makes little sense to have an image without Geo-referencing.  (How would it be displayed on a map?)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are definitely right! It was wrong for me to assume that using GDAL > Translate (Convert format) would auto-assign geographic coordinates to the image vertices. Thought that since its possible to customize the extent/bounding box of a raster via the Python console. Moving on, I georeferenced the image to an extent that falls within [-180,90,180,-90] and the image could be ingested fine. However, after loading the ee.Image as a ui.Thumbnail, the dimensions seem warped, and the image resolution is very poor i.e. blurry.

As such, instead of using the ui.Thumbnail method, I embed the original *.jpg image into a ui.Chart. It works fine now. Thanks!